# How to bind hungry delete for Clojure in Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure

I just started experimenting with Clojure and it is bugging me that I can't use c-hungry-delete-backwards because clojure-mode is not based on cc-mode. In other words, I want to make C-c C-backspace delete all whitespace to the left of the cursor until it hits non-whitespace.

How can I make hungry delete or the equivalent work with Clojure + emacs? I'm not using swank or slime right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my .emacs file at home I use:

```
(load "cc-mode")
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<delete>") 'c-hungry-delete-forward)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-<backspace>") 'c-hungry-delete-backwards)
```

Which gives me hungry delete everywhere.

On the other hand at work I have installed the hungry-delete package from package.el which provides hungry-delete as a minor mode which you can add to your clojure mode hook.

Comment: Thank you very much! For the record, I installed hungry-delete via package.el and that let me use (global-set-key (kbd "C-c <C-backspace>") 'hungry-delete-backward) in my .emacs to have hungry delete available in all modes, which is even cooler from my point of view than hooking it to clojure-mode.

Comment: For deleting only whitespace backward, calling delete-horizontal-whitespace with a prefix (C-u M-\\) will suffice and it requires no customization.

Comment: I think the behavior of `delete-horizontal-whitespace` isn't quite the same; it won't delete newlines.